# ms access 2013, error 2501 while opening form on Win7 enterprise, but not on Win7 professional

Tags: ms-access-2013, environment

A few weeks ago a failure appeared on every newly installed or reinstalled desktop pc's. (100+ pc's in the office, 10+ affected)
Failure description: some of the forms doesn't open with Docmd.OpenForm. I get error 2501. The Form.Open event doesn't run. The failure is stable. The applications didn't change since months. The same file runs fine on old installations.

I tried:
 * decompile + compile + compact & repair on affected pc's
 * import to new file (order: tables, queries, modules, forms; with compact & repair in every step)
 * removed code using ActiveX & ActiveX reference
 * tested the queries behind the affected forms, they are OK
 * no errors show up in form editor
 * deleting the VBA module of the form
 * ticket to the IT departement - no reply so far
 * ritual scolding and cursing of M$

The forms are opening after deleting their modules. Obviously, I need those modules. :)
If I only delete the Form.Open, Form.Load event, then they open with errors. (" error between the application and the OLE service provider or ActiveX controller"). I also get the error with Form.Close. If I delete the whole module, I don't get this error. 
That error 2501 shows up with totally empty(a single rem line) Form.Open().

We have Windows 7 SP1 build 7601, and Office 2013 plus 64 bit build 4771 on all pc's. Working installations have W7 professional, affected pc's have enterprise version. One affected application has access backend, the other has MYSQL.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: we had english Windows 7 with hungarian MS Office. Access forms are working properly after  changing language for non-unicode programs to hungarian.
How to do it: local admin privileges required. Go to control panel --> Region & language --> administrative --> change system locale.

Remark: Changing it may break other non-unicode applications.